# Is deriving square from rectangle a violation of Liskov's Substitution Principle?

Tags: oop, liskov-substitution-principle

I am new to design and learning the design principles.

It says deriving square from rectangle is a classic example of violation of Liskov's Substitution Principle.

If that's the case, what should be the correct design?

Comment: Confused why flagged as opinion-based question? This is a valid software design question

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I believe the reasoning is something like this:

Let's say you have a method that accepts a rectangle and adjusts its width:

```
public void SetWidth(Rectangle rect, int width)
{
    rect.Width = width;
}
```

It should be perfectly reasonable, given what a rectangle is, to assume that this test would pass:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 20); // width, height

SetWidth(rect, 100);

Assert.AreEqual(20, rect.Height);
```

... because changing a rectangle's width does not affect its height.

However, let's say you've derived a new Square class from Rectangle. By definition, a square has height and width always equal. Let's try that test again:

```
Rectangle rect = new Square(20); // both width and height

SetWidth(rect, 100);

Assert.AreEqual(20, rect.Height);
```

That test will fail, because setting a square's width to 100 will also change its height.

Thus, Liskov's substitution principle is violated by deriving Square from Rectangle.

The "is-a" rule makes sense in the "real world" (a square is definitely a kind of rectangle), but not always in the world of software design.

**Edit**

To answer your question, the correct design should probably be that both Rectangle and Square derive from a common "Polygon" or "Shape" class, which does not enforce any rules regarding width or height.

Comment: Second example, should the assert be testing for 50?  BTW, in the "real world" a square is either not mutable (is drawing on a page) or it can cease to be a square when a force is applied (its made out of rubber), IOW in the real world an object can change type dynamically something we don't model very well in programming languages.

Comment: Oops well spotted on the second example. The test is right - the ctor parameter is wrong. Clipboard inheritence bug! I will fix it now.

Answer (score 94):

The answer depends on mutability. If your rectangle and square classes are immutable, then `Square` is really a subtype of `Rectangle` and it's perfectly OK to derive first from second. Otherwise, `Rectangle` and `Square` could both expose an `IRectangle` with no mutators, but deriving one from the other is wrong since neither type is properly a subtype of the other.

Comment: Perceptive. I suppose you could generalise slightly further by saying that the truth of the statement "A is a subtype of B" depends on the public interface exposed by B. A smaller interface (e.g. an interface lacking mutators) reduces the amount you can "do" with concrete objects of that type or its subtypes, but gives you more opportunities for subtyping.

Comment: @Anton I would say `IShape` makes more sense than the `IRectangle` in this context. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think so. `IShape` would make sense in a context which considered all shapes, including non-rectangular ones, but *this* context we're discussing here doesn't. We're talking about just squares and rectangles here; triangles and circles need not apply.

Comment: If rectangle and square classes are immutable, then, most likely, Rectangle will have a constructor in form 'Rectangle(width, height)' which Square class will need to re-implement and that doesn't make much sense from practical viewpoint.

Comment: This answer further explains the immutability concept: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/338817/93601

Comment: what is meant by the phrase "expose an IRectangle"? I suggest improving the answer with a more descriptive phrase

Answer (score 6):

I don't agree that deriving square from rectangle necessarily violates LSP.

In Matt's example, if you have code that relies on width and height being independent, then it does in fact violate LSP.

If however, you can substitute a rectangle for a square everywhere in your code without breaking any assumptions then you're not violating LSP.

So it really comes down to what the abstraction rectangle means in *your* solution.

Comment: This is correct, but it's kind of pointless to have a Square class unless you use its invariants in the program :)

Comment: I could imagine having a code base that works on image rectangles. Then you get an idea for a performance optimization if the rectangles happen to be square. So yes, you are using the width/height invariant internally in the square, but it is invisible to the outside world (Only if no assumptions are made in the code on the orthogonality of width and height, of course).

Comment: I agree, but this doesn't cover the case of someone else using *Rectangle* invariants, like ones suggested by Matt above. I didn't notice this when I wrote the first comment.

Answer (score 6):

I've been struggling with this problem a lot lately and thought I'd add my hat into the ring:

```
public class Rectangle {

    protected int height;    
    protected int width;

    public Rectangle (int height, int width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int computeArea () { return this.height * this.width; }
    public int getHeight () { return this.height; }
    public int getWidth () { return this.width; }

}

public class Square extends Rectangle {

    public Square (int sideLength) {
        super(sideLength, sideLength);
    }

}

public class ResizableRectangle extends Rectangle {

    public ResizableRectangle (int height, int width) {
        super(height, width);
    }

    public void setHeight (int height) { this.height = height; }
    public void setWidth (int width) { this.width = width; }

}
```

Notice the last class, `ResizableRectangle`. By moving the "resizableness" into a subclass, we get code re-use while actually improving our model. Think of it like this: a square cannot be freely resized while remaining a square, whereas non-square rectangles can. Not *all* rectangles can be resized though, since a *square* is a rectangle (and it cannot be freely resized while retaining its "identity"). (o_O) So it makes sense to make a base `Rectangle` class which is not resizable, since this is an extra property of *some* rectangles.

Comment: Note that due to the visibility of the fields, it is possible to make subclasses of `Square` that aren't square by having a different width and height.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that what is being described is really not a "type" but an cumulative emergent property.

All you really have is a quadrilateral and that both "squareness" and "rectangleness" are just emergent artifacts derived from properties of the angles and sides.

The entire concept of "Square" (or even rectangle) is just an abstract representation of a collection of properties of the object in relation to each other and the object in question, not the type of object in and of it's self.

This is where thinking of the problem in the context of a typeless language can help, because it's not the type that determines if it's "a square" but the actual properties of the object that determines if it's "a square".

I guess if you want to take the abstraction even further you wouldn't even say you have a quadrilateral but that you have a polygon or even just a shape.

Comment: I'm maybe not understanding the distinction between a type and a representation of an objects properties/relationships. I would think the latter would serve as a somewhat informal definition of a type. Your last paragraph seems to argue against deriving from types entirely because you could always remove another layer of abstraction (e.g. there are no shapes, just collections of points and lines).

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume we have the class Rectangle with the two (for simplicity public) properties width,height. We can change those two properties: r.width=1, r.height=2.
Now we say a Square is_a Rectangle. But though the claim is "a square will behave like a rectangle" we can't set .width=1 and .height=2 on a square object (your class probably adjusts the width if you set the height and vice versa). So there's at least one case where an object of type Square doesn't behave like a Rectangle and therefore you cannot substitute them (completely).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that OOD/OOP techniques exist to enable software to represent the real world.  In the real world a square is a rectangle that has equal sides.  The square is a square only because it has equal sides, not because it decided to be a square. Therefore, the OO program needs to deal with it.  Of course, if the routine instantiating the object wants it to be square, it could specify the length property and the width property as equal to the same amount.  If the program using the object needs to know later if it is square, it needs only to ask it.  The object could have a read-only Boolean property called “Square”.   When the calling routine invokes it, the object can return (Length = Width).  Now this can be the case even if the rectangle object is immutable.  In addition, if the rectangle is indeed immutable, the value of the Square property can be set in the constructor and be done with it.  Why then is this an issue?  The LSP requires sub-objects to be immutable to apply and square being a sub-object of a rectangle is often used as an example of its violation.  But that doesn’t seem to be good design because when the using routine invokes the object as “objSquare”, must know its inner detail.  Wouldn’t it be better if it didn’t care whether the rectangle was square or not?  And that would be because the rectangle’s methods would be correct regardless.  Is there a better example of when the LSP is violated?

One more question: how is an object made immutable?  Is there an “Immutable” property that can be set at instantiation?

I found the answer and it is what I expected.  Since I'm a VB .NET developer, that is what I'm interested in.  But the concepts are the same across languages.  In VB .NET you create immutable classes by making the properties read-only and you use the New constructor to allow the instantiating routine to specify property values when the object is created.  You can also use constants for some of the properties and they will always be the same.  From creation forward the object is immutable.

Answer (score -3):

Its pretty simple :)   The more 'base' the class (the first in the derivation chain) should be the most general.

For example shape -> Rectangle -> Square.

Here a square is a special case of a rectangle (with constrained dimensions) and a Rectangle is a special case of a shape.

Said another way - use the "is a" test.  A squire is a rectangle.  But a rectange is not always a square.

Comment: This is the real world concept, but not the software design concept.