# How to prevent violation of Liskov Substitution

Tags: solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

Everywhere I could read about Liskov Substitution, only 1 example is available which is Rectangle and Square and It is explained how we can violate it but no corrective actions are described.
One such example is available at [This](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-are-the-solid-principles-in-java?aid=5082902844932096&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=edpresso-dynamic&gclid=Cj0KCQjwmIuDBhDXARIsAFITC_4-7d7OzHBTzLq6d9E4zI5bbVpX4AqbFhbDi02IhynjZ9UG1iOKGTAaAg4-EALw_wcB) link :

I want to know corrective steps If we are violating it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: [Is deriving square from rectangle a violation of Liskov's Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1030521/1371329)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `Rectangle` and `Square` the corrective action is simply, don't implement inheritance between them. The LSP tells us that neither is a parent or child of the other, so keep them separate. They can still be siblings, e.g. both can inherit from `Shape`; but they are separate branches of the `Shape` hierarchy.

The other potential solution to an LSP violation between two classes is to redefine one or both of them. This isn't a viable solution for `Rectangle` and `Square` because they are defined mathematically; but in a scenario where you have control of the abstraction or its implementation, you can edit the contract to fit the code or vice versa.